# eclipse example template with an editor or multi-page editor not running due to following errors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

eclipse example PDE template with an editor or multi-page editor not running.
error log show following errors in new workerbench window.

**1.Warning:** The environment variable HOME is not set.
**2.Warning:** EGit couldn't detect the installation path "GitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level

Where and how to set these values.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score -1):

Those are NOT ERRORS.  Do not overreact.  As it said, it's looking for the environmental variable HOME to have been set, but you can just go fill in information that it would guess from that in the Git preferences.  These messages do not appear in newer versions of eGit.

And just because you opened a Runtime Workbench does not mean your editor will be automatically opened.  If it's not opening when you try to open one of its supported fie types, open a question with the stack traces of its failures.

Comment: I have set the environment variable HOME as %USERPROFILE% but still same warning and I have no idea how to set GitPrefix.
and kindly let me know how to run the this template editor plugin.
I have tried may times but I am not able to figure it out how to run plugin.